# Freemarker: Display data in grid using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, freemarker

I have a list with PATHs to photos in freemarker and I need to display photos in HTML page. I iterate my list like that

```
<#if photos?has_content>
    <#list photos as photo>
        <img src=${photo}
    </#list>
</#if>
```

And also I have HTML page that uses bootstrap classes for displaying this photos in grid (3 columns)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="photo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="photo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="photo"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Number of rows depends on the number of photos, but it couldn't be predicted. I don't know how to add opening and closing div for row after every first and third photo.

Hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks!

[image: that is how it should look]

Comment: you could use javascript/jquery to create the rows and add the images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `?chunk` (http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_chunk) for that:

```
<div class="container">
  <#list photos?chunk(3) as row>
    <div class="row">
      <#list row as photo>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="photo"><img src="${photo}"></div>
        </div>        
      </#list>
    </div>
  <#else>
    <div class="something">No photos</div>
  </#list>
</div>
```